# Would pausing sleep for a second be better than constantly calling the time function to see if the next second had passed

Tags: c

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
void TemperatureCtrl(float curTemp, float TargetTemp, float errTemp);
float TemperatureGet();
int direction = 0;
int main()
{ 
    float CurTemp;
    time_t tim = 0;
    struct  tm ttm;
    time_t tim2 = 0;
    while (1)
    {
         time(&tim2);
         if (tim != tim2)
         {
            tim = tim2;
            localtime_r(&tim, &ttm);
  
            CurTemp = TemperatureGet();
            printf("%02d:%02d:%02d Temp:%.1f℃\r\n", ttm.tm_hour, ttm.tm_min, ttm.tm_sec, CurTemp);
            TemperatureCtrl(CurTemp, 23.0, 0.5);
        }
    }
}
```

maybe used sleep(1000) is better ?
Use sleep () to pause for a second and let the thread hang for a second. It will be better for CPU usage.

Comment: Yes, using `sleep()` will allow the Operating System to spend CPU resources on other tasks or save energy. If the pause were very short or you were on a single-threaded embedded system, the situation would be different.

Comment: Used on a temperature controller.Used to output temperature and time once a second.This is code written by someone else, and my first experience with this kind of project.I think there's something wrong with his code.

Comment: What else does this sensor do?  How much power would be saved if `sleep(1000)` were to be used?  Because `sleep(1000)` has definite drawbacks - you won't actually get output "every second".  You'll get output eveery second plus some overhead, and the output won't happen shortly after the clock rolls over to the next second - it will happen at any time during that second.  Put those two together and using `sleep(1000)` will likely cause output for some seconds to be skipped entirely.

Comment: *It will be better for CPU usage.*  I'm not sure why there's a widespread notion that using CPU cycles is a bad thing.  Unless there's some benefit to be gained such as lower power consumption or the ability to do other things. ***there's nothing wrong with maxing out your CPU utilization***.  That's what the )!%&!% thing was made for and bought to do, and if you don't use them, the [idle loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_(CPU)) will.  CPU cycles are not some magic resource that if you don't use them now you'll be able to use them later.

Comment: I see. Thank you!I've learned things from you that I didn't understand before!

Comment: `<iostream>` is not a valid C include header, unless you installed a library (or something similar) that provides that *strangely named* header.

Comment: Yes, they told me it was a C project, but I had a feeling it was actually a C++ project.I joined a college student project, maybe I should get out of it and try my own project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> maybe used sleep(1000) is better?

Yes.

Calling sleep will suspend the current thread for a specified time interval. Other threads could take the CPU to do their work, it's more efficient.

Constantly calling the time function is too inefficient. The current thread occupies the CPU, but there is no meaningful work to do.

Comment: *Yes.*  No.  There's nowhere near enough information in the question to blindly conclude the posted code would be improved by using `sleep(1000)`

Comment: Generally speaking, "sleep" is better. But I'd like to hear about the case under that constantly calling  time function is better:)

Comment: [No, generally speaking, `sleep()` ***sucks*** in any solution requiring anything close to reliable timing](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html): "The `sleep()` function shall cause the calling thread to be suspended from execution until either the number of realtime seconds specified by the argument seconds has elapsed **or a signal is delivered** to the calling thread and its action is to invoke a signal-catching function or to terminate the process. **The suspension time may be longer than requested** due to the scheduling of other activity by the system."

Comment: The time slept can be shorter, or it can be longer, and you can't do anything about it.  Your standard for "better" is horribly low.